# DBeaver PostgreSQL Database - SCRAM authentication is not supported by this driver

Tags: postgresql, dbeaver, pg-jdbc

I am trying to add a PostgreSQL database to DBeaver and am getting the following error when I try to connect to the database. I'm using DBeaver Version 7.2.3.202010191702. And after receiving this message I installed the latest version of the JDK (11.0.9) and pgJDBC (postgresql-42.2.18.jar). I've not had PostgreSQL on this machine yet, so it's a fresh install of the latest version (v13). Any suggestions?

> SCRAM authentication is not supported by this driver. You need JDK >= 8 and pgjdbc >= 42.2.0 (not ".jre" vesions)

Comment: I guess you didn't install it in the right way, and DBeaver is still using the old version.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I had same error and in my situation I had old database drivers. These steps fixed it for me:

- Go to Database Driver Manager
- Select PostgreSQL (either double click or single select and then "Edit ...")
- Click on "Download/Update"
- Choose newer version (see bold version text) e.g. 42.2.18 for org.postgresql:postgresql:RELEASE
- Press "Download"

Answer (score 0):

Even using all the tips and tricks found on SO I was not able to connect to PGSQL 14 DBs.
I fixed it by using `PostgreSQL (Old)` driver, and it now works.

Answer (score 0):

The problem I faced was identical, and what resolved it for me was:

1. Removing the previous PostgreSQL JDBC from the lib folder.
2. Downloading the latest PostgreSQL JDBC.
3. Substituting the old JDBC with the new one.

Answer (score -1):

I had a problem similar to yours. This is the way to fix it:

1. open folder `PostgreSQL\14\data`, edit `postgresql.config`  fix password_encryption to `md5`
2. alter `all` METHOD value to `password` in `pg_hba.conf`
3. restart postgres server

Answer (score -2):

In my case, JRE version postgres being used in Pom.xml. Update it to the latest version and it should work

Comment: Please add more details with code.