# Can't connect to databases in DBeaver

Tags: postgresql, dbeaver

I'm having problems trying to connect to databases with DBeaver. I've managed to connect to one database fine with no problems. However, any additional connections is causing issues.

I keep getting the error

> SCRAM authentication is not supported by this driver. You need JDK >= 8 and pgjdbc >= 42.2.0 (not ".jre" versions)

I've tried the exact same details in pgadmin, and can get into the database just fine.

I just much prefer DBeaver as pgadmin seems to lack some really basic features like autocompletion.

I've reinstalled postgres and dbeaver multiple times, ensuring that its the latest version of each, still nothing.

Comment: What steps have you taken to solve this? Does this answer help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64546286/2221001 ?

Comment: As the error message says: you need to upgrade the JDBC driver (pgAdmin doesn't use Java so the JDBC driver is not relevant for that)

Comment: @JNevill So I followed that https://imgur.com/a/K6kzX0I I went to the highest version that appears and clicked download, but that doesn't fix anything.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I checked and I get openjdk version "11.0.14.1" 2022-02-08.

Which should meet the requirements of JDK >=8

Comment: It's the JDBC [_driver_](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/), not the JDK you need to update

Comment: Thanks turns out it was the JDK that needed updating as it needed a .jar not .jre. Furthermore DBeaver was holding on to old outdated libraries for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed the issue. It appears that DBeaver was holding on to an outdated library, which was being checked first, and therefore failing the test.

Steps to solve issue.

1. Download latest JDBC and move to \Program Files\DBeaver\shared_drivers
2. Open DBeaver and click Database -> Driver Manager
3. Double click on PostgreSQL
4. Under libraries click Add file and find the new JDBC
5. Delete any of the previous libraries, so it remains the only one